# ubuntu hyper-v vm stuck at initramfs

Tags: boot, 18.04, virtualbox, hyper-v

I am new to Ubuntu and getting an issue at boot. Did some stuff and now the screen seems to stuck at initramfs. Here is what I did

- Installed a ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS version through Hyper-v on windows. The disk size was initially 12 GB.
- I logged into it just fine without any issue.
- Turned it off and then next day expanded the virtual hard-disk size to 100 GB thinking that 12 GB was a bit low. This was done through Hyper-v Manager (through settings)
- Ubuntu vm did not recognize the increase in size and therefore I started to evaluate options.
- Came across some gparted tool and installed it on ubuntu.
- Before running gparted I then turned off the vm and shrank the virtual hard-disk size to 50 gb, thinking that 100 GB was a bit high.
- Turned on the vm and came across the black screen of initramfs
- I do not want to start from scratch and thus would request some ubuntu expert to assist me in fixing this.

[image: ubuntu stuck at boot hyper-v]

Answer (score 0):

I believe (and I am not an expert) that the UUID refers to a storage device that used to exist but now doesn't.

I think this might be due to the fact that you shrank the disk. When you expand the disk, the OS may put files into the expanded disk space. When you shrank that, those disappeared putting you in the situation you are now.

I know this isn't an answer, but an attempt at an explanation.

(EDIT: when shrinking the disk, you may actually have removed some sectors that were there before the expansion)

Oh, and also, a good rule of thumb is to never shrink a disk.

Comment: yeah i realize that .. but the problem is that the unused space wasn't detected by ubuntu. that is the reason i went ahead and installed gparted to fix the unused space. I would expect that until i had fixed it there should have been nothing on it.

Comment: So initially the size was 12GB which was correctly detected by ubuntu. the increase to 100 GB was visible on the windows (through Hyper v Manager) but not inisde ubuntu. Ubuntu still showed 12 GB. Per my understanding the shrinking by 50 gb should not have affected anything on ubuntu (it was still larger than the 12 GB that ubuntu had been showing)